# pdfLaTeX epstopdf converts all text to monotype font

Tags: latex, pdflatex

When including .eps files with `\includegraphics` and compiling with pdfLaTeX, I get all fonts in monotype font even though the original .eps file has another font specified, e.g. Helvetica or Arial. I've tested both Helvetica and Arial (the latter of which is installed on my Windows 10 system) to make sure it wasn't an issue of whether the font is installed.

Here are the two example eps files I'm using to test it:

https://github.com/skhiggins/test_epstopdf/blob/master/sample_eps_arial.eps

https://github.com/skhiggins/test_epstopdf/blob/master/sample_eps_helvetica.eps

Opening the .eps files in a text editor, I confirmed they declare the fonts as Helvetica and Arial, respectively, using e.g. `%%DocumentNeededResources: font Arial`. If I open the .eps files using gsview they appear correctly. However, when I compile a pdf in LaTeX the font of the graphs is monotype. (If I run `epstopdf` in the command line, I also get monotype font.) Here is the LaTeX code that I compile with pdflatex.exe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sample_eps_helvetica.eps}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sample_eps_arial.eps}

\end{document}
```

Both graphics appear in the pdf as follows, with a monotype font :
[image]

I already tried the obvious things like uninstalling and reinstalling MiKTeX. Here is the log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.1.10)  10 JAN 2020 10:12
entering extended mode
**C:/Dropbox/Latex_code/test_epstopdf/epstopdf_MWE.tex
(C:/Dropbox/Latex_code/test_epstopdf/epstopdf_MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
) ("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2019/11/01 v1.3d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) ("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
) ("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf.sty"
Package: epstopdf 2019/11/24 v2.7 Conversion with epstopdf on the fly (HO)
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2019/11/24 v2.7 Base part for package epstopdf
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) ("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
))) ("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
))))) ("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
42.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 460.
)) (C:\Dropbox\Latex_code\test_epstopdf\build\epstopdf_MWE.aux)
\openout1 = `epstopdf_MWE.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
("C:\Dropbox\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count88
\scratchdimen=\dimen105
\scratchbox=\box27
\nofMPsegments=\count89
\nofMParguments=\count90
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count91
\MPscratchDim=\dimen106
\MPnumerator=\count92
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count93
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
)
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <sample_eps_helvetica.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-01-10 10:10:40
(epstopdf)                    size: 13204 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <sample_eps_helvetica-eps-converted-to.pdf>

(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-01-10 10:12:32
(epstopdf)                    size: 11003 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=sample_eps_helvetica-eps-co
nverted-to.pdf sample_eps_helvetica.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 9.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file ./sample_eps_helvetica-eps-converted-to.pdf)
: PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
<sample_eps_helvetica-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=1, 397.485pt x 289.08pt>
File: sample_eps_helvetica-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use sample_eps_helvetica-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: sample_eps_helvetica-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on inp
ut line 9.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 390.0pt x 283.64493pt.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <sample_eps_arial.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-01-10 10:10:40
(epstopdf)                    size: 13200 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <sample_eps_arial-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-01-10 10:12:33
(epstopdf)                    size: 11003 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=sample_eps_arial-eps-conver
ted-to.pdf sample_eps_arial.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 10.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file ./sample_eps_arial-eps-converted-to.pdf): PD
F inclusion: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
<sample_eps_arial-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=2, 397.485pt x 289.08pt>
File: sample_eps_arial-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use sample_eps_arial-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: sample_eps_arial-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on input l
ine 10.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 390.0pt x 283.64493pt.

Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--11
[][]
 []

[1

{C:/Users/Sean Higgins/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./sa
mple_eps_helvetica-eps-converted-to.pdf>] [2 <./sample_eps_arial-eps-converted-
to.pdf>] (C:\Dropbox\Latex_code\test_epstopdf\build\epstopdf_MWE.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1503 strings out of 492484
 22174 string characters out of 3129678
 82863 words of memory out of 3000000
 5860 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3938 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,4n,32p,365b,115s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Drop
box/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on C:\Dropbox\Latex_code\test_epstopdf\build\epstopdf_MWE.pdf (2
 pages, 27497 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 25 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 11 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck03F.png

Comment: Can you also post the resulting files from epstopdf?

Comment: https://github.com/skhiggins/test_epstopdf/blob/master/sample_eps_arial-eps-converted-to.pdf
https://github.com/skhiggins/test_epstopdf/blob/master/sample_eps_helvetica-eps-converted-to.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I just checked with `pdffonts` if the fonts are embedded. One difference I noticed is that I get `TFCPOY+Helvetica` while your file has `FRDWKK+Helvetica`. No idea what this means or if this is significant

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I don't know the reason, but the solution for me was to reinstall Miktex to the previous version (basic-miktex-2.9.6850-x64).